# Create Text Graphics with Flat-Style Padded Background Boxes

Tags: premiere, subtitles

I'm using Premiere. Was wondering the best way (base application or if there's a good recommended plugin) to get this style text graphic:

https://twitter.com/CNET/status/1122999001119318017

(0:10 in video)

Where the flat background boxes can be set with a certain amount of padding, and automatically expand according to the length of the text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to create this, from the video you linked above:

[image]

- If you want to create a title template that can adjust to (almost) whatever words you type in it, you're going to have to use After Effects.
- In Premiere, you can create title templates, but they're not going to adjust to whatever length of word you use.
  The following link takes you to a video that offers a good run-down of [the latest title tools in Premiere](https://youtu.be/WgPC5qum4Zc?t=419), with which you can create templates that look like what you have in mind -- by the way, you could achieve a similar look with the old Title Tool: create a black matte, give it an opacity of, say, 30%, and place it under your title words.

Comment: (you could get someone who has after effects to make it for you, and add it into your premiere project)